# Object overwriting not working

Tags: javascript, object

My JavaScript object is:

```
var MyObject = {
    DOM: function(tagName){
        if(!this.isElement){
            var found = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            this.isElement = true;
            for(i in found)
                this[i] = found[i];
        } else{
            var found = this[0].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            for(i in found)
                this[i] = found[i];
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly:

```
MyObject.DOM("div");
```

The problem is that when I log the object again:

```
MyObject.DOM("div");
console.log(MyObject);
```

The problem is that it logs:

> > Object {0: div#lower.cl, 1: div.higher, find: function, isElement: true}

But actually I want it to log:

> > Object {find: function}

So I don't want it to keep the found elements when I run the `MyObject` again.

So really I just want to reload the object every time I use it.

Comment: The behavior which you are saying does not correspond to the code that you posted.

Comment: Is `DOM` supposed to be `find` in the object code?

Comment: @user3719477 ... partially. See also the Object logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can implement this. It's best if you stick to keeping your objects as immutable as possible. You're trying to use one instance of one object to do everything, and that won't work:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.length = 0;
}

MyObject.prototype.DOM = function (tagName) {
    var found = new MyObject(),
        batch,
        toSearch,
        i,
        j,
        z = 0;

    if (this === MyObject) {
        toSearch = [document];
    } else {
        toSearch = Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < toSearch.length; i += 1) {
        batch = toSearch[i].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (j = 0; j < batch.length; j += 1) {
            found[found.length] = batch[j];
            found.length += 1;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

MyObject.DOM = MyObject.prototype.DOM;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sygdm/

Answer (score 0):

You can add sort of 'private' fields to your classes like so:

```
var MyObject = (function() {
  var instance = {};
  return {
    DOM: function(tagName){
        if(!instance.isElement){
            var found = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            instance.isElement = true;
            for(i in found)
                instance[i] = found[i];
        } else{
            var found = instance[0].getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            for(i in found)
                instance[i] = found[i];
        }
        return this;
    }
  }
})();
```

Not sure if that is what you want, though.

Comment: Just return this at the end instead of instance :)

Comment: If you explain it to me I will accept your answer @LuanNico

Comment: Edited the answer. Returning this instead of instance will allow chaining.